# error:unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio

i'm having an issue and i can't resolve it.When i'm compiling i'm having an issue with all my functions, i put a fonction here as an example. The error is C2244:unable to match function definition to an existing declaration.
So this is my header file.

```
template <typename T>
class Gestionnaire {
public:
    Gestionnaire();
    ~Gestionnaire();

    bool addElement(const T* element);
    bool removeElement(const T* element);

    template < typename P>
    bool removeContent(P& predicat);

    template < typename P>
    T* findElement(P& predicat) const;

    bool findElement(const T& element) const;

    private:
        std::list<T*> liste_;
};  

template<typename P>
template <typename T>
bool Gestionnaire<T>::removeContent(P& predicat) {
        std::remove_if(liste_begin(), liste_.end(), predicat);
}
```

Comment: Look in the preview box to check that your post is formatted correctly before submitting it

Comment: @LogicStuff sorry i added the wrong function in here

Comment: @M.M sorry i'm still new here i don't really know how to do this

Comment: There's a box to the right when you are entering your text, titled "How to Format"

Comment: put the P and T lines the other way around

Comment: @M.M thanks it worked, but why does it matter? and how does it work

Comment: they've got to be in the same order as the declaration;   the template `removeContent` is inside the template `Gestionnaire<T>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch `template<typename P>` and `template <typename T>` to the same order as they appear in the declaration. The first list of template parameters is for the class template, the second for the templated member function:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename P>
bool Gestionnaire<T>::removeContent(P& predicat) {
        std::remove_if(liste_begin(), liste_.end(), predicat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful! i got a question tho, if i use T as my parameter and i only use P in my implementation what should the order be? cause it is not compiling if i keep it in that order. Thanks

Comment: @MarcElKhoury: What do you mean, you use it only in your implementation?

Comment: it means i only use it inside the function not in the function header. template<typename T>
template<typename P>
bool Gestionnaire<T>::trouverElement(const T& element) const {

that's the header of my function but i only use P inside the function

Comment: @MarcElKhoury: The order remains the same, but when using it, you have to manually specify the type P. If you have a new problem, then please ask a new question (preferably with an [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: i can't ask another question today i'm still new here. But should i  declare it template<typename P> inside the function or outside? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @MarcElKhoury: You declare it exactly the same way. Maybe you should read up on templates (e.g. on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates))